# How to enable CORS in the Cloud Storage's public URL

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I'm using google storage public bucket for serving binary resources on the web right now.

As the docs mentioned
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

```
The authenticated browser download endpoint storage.cloud.google.com does not allow CORS requests. Note that the Google Cloud console provides this endpoint for each object's public URL link.
```

So in order to allow CORS, I need to put my proxy server in front.

I'm not sure there is a way I don't know to enable me to fetch resources directly from Cloud Storage with CORS but without having a relay server.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

Comment: @JohnHanley I have already to config the CORS but as the doc mentioned, CORS is not supported for the public URL generated via google console.

Comment: So if I need to generate the public URL myself I still need my proxy server, That's why I'm asking here. Sorry for the unclarification.

Comment: After your edit: you are using the wrong endpoint for public buckets. The endpoint in your post update requires authorization credentials. See Brandon's answer below.

Comment: OK You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the URLs for objects that you're getting from the console. Those URLs use the domain `storage.cloud.google.com`. Because that domain allows callers to use their Google account cookies for authentication, its capabilities are intentionally kept very limited, and one such limitation is blocking cross-origin requests.

Instead, configure CORS using the [standard Cloud Storage tools](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#gsutil), then link your users to a URL like `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name`, which will work fine with CORS. That will only work for publicly readable objects, but that sounds like what you've got.

Comment: There is a typo in the second URL: `googelapis`

Comment: I just found out that, Actually I've run into this problem because of `Cache-Control`. So basically Cloud Storage caches me the version with no-cors.

Comment: That's why I got confused about about how it doesn't work after I've changed the cors config. Hope it help other who run into this.